# Using syscall 30 in MIPS assembly language

Tags: mips, system-calls, mips32

Hi I was wondering exactly what the syscall 30 does, how it works, and where it can applied.

I am working on a project where the user has a certain amount of time to input a string. How would I use syscall 30 to set a time limit?

Thanks!

Comment: Syscall 30 is a way of calling into the operating system or other supervisory piece of software. It is a generic term, and has not much to do with any particular machine. **What is your operating system**? The answer to that will answer what does the syscall do, and that’s the starting point before anyone can answer “how to use that syscall from assembly?”

Answer (score 1):

The `syscall` functionality in `MIPS` is actually a way to easily call to some form of system software, of which an operating system is one example.

For example, [this page](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html) details the system calls for `MARS` while [this one](http://students.cs.tamu.edu/tanzir/csce350/reference/syscalls.html) is for `SPIM`, two of the no doubt *many* system environments available from educational institutions.

What `syscall 30` does depends *entirely* upon the system software you are using. It's *possible* that you may be using MARS since `syscall 30` on that system gives you the current time. If that's the case, you can set a time limit on an operation with the following pseudo-code:

```
syscall 30 to get current time
set start time to current time
while (current time - start time) is less than time limit:
    do something intelligent
    syscall 30 to get current time
```

You will, of course, need to turn that in to MIPS assembly code (as part of your education), assemblers that can understand natural language are few and far between :-)

Comment: I am using MARS. The lower 32 bits stored in $a0 just comes out as a large number? How can I interpret this as a time value?

Comment: Sebastian, it's in the link I gave: Service 30 - System time comes from java.util.Date.getTime() as milliseconds since 1 January 1970.